# Flask: How to manually store session data

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I have a flask app with some ajax calls which uses mySQL to store session data and a session id.

I use Flask's session to hold the session id but have been unable to make the session id persist across views.

This all works when run locally, but not once I push it to the server.

How can I store a unique session ID either using session's or otherwise ?

```
from flask import session

@app.route('/get_data/', methods=['POST'])
def get_form_data():
    session['session_id'] = random_key
    if request.method == "POST":
        ...

@app.route('/process_data/')
def process_data():
    get_from_db(session['session_id'])
```

HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $("#chart").load("/get_data/", function() {
        $('#check_count').load('/process_data/', function() {
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

EDIT: I've set the secret key for session use and sessions work in a particular function.

Sessions work in the `get_data` function. The next function also needs the session data and fails to find the key.

Comment: Did you find a solution yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's many threads about how the "session" object on flask doesn't work when calling views with Ajax.

I'm very new to this and wanted a simple work around that didn't involve a Redis server. I also running this project as a free tier on OpenShift and adding more cartridges just to pass around a session ID felt like overkill.

Thus, I ended up storing the "session ID" in the `URL` as a query and used the templates to add it.

```
$("#data_chart").load("/process_data" + {{ session_id }}");


@app.route('/process_data')
def process_data():
    session_id = request.args.get("session_id")
    # do a bunch of stuff here

    # propagate the ID for other views to access=
    session_string = '?session_id=%' % session_id
    return render_template('output.html', session_id=session_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the app's secret key ?

From the [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#sessions) website:

> In order to use sessions you have to set a secret key.

```
# set the secret key.  keep this really secret:
app.secret_key = 'A0Zr98j/3yX R~XHH!jmN]LWX/,?RT'
```

Comment: I did set the secret key, thanks. The session works run locally. There's many SO questions about this topic but they aren't helping me.

Comment: @wbg - Do your sessions not work at all or just not working in Ajax requests ?

Comment: Sessions r working in general. Failure occurs when run on server. I've read that ajax doesn't carry cookies.tbh I'm not sure I know what that means..

Comment: I did solve this forgot to accept own answer. Very simple way to store data is in the uri itself.